# Decoding not working with Base64

Tags: javascript, html, encode

Encoding my URL works perfectly with base-64 encoding. So does decoding but not with the string literal **variable**.

This works:

```
document.write(atob("hi"));
```

This does not:

```
var tempvar = "hello";
document.write(atob(tempvar));
```

What am I doing wrong? Nothing is displayed. But if I quote `"tempvar"`, then it of course works but is not the same thing since `"tempvar"` is a string, not a variable.

Comment: Browser returned you an exception. Any chance you have read the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your Question

> *What am I doing wrong?*

The string being passed to [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) is a string literal of length 5 (and not technically a base-64 encoded string). The browser console should reveal an exception in the error log (see explanation in ***The cause*** below).

### The cause

Per the MDN documentation of [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob):

> #### Throws
>
> Throws a [DOMException](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/DOMException) if the length of passed-in string is not a multiple of 4. <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)</sup>

The length of the string literal "*hello*" (i.e. *5*) is not a multiple of 4. Thus the exception is thrown instead of returning the decoded version of the string literal.

### A Solution

One solution is to either use a string that has actually been encoded (e.g. with [btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)) or at least has a length of four (e.g. using [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)). See the snippet below for an example.

```js
var tempvar = "hello";
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(readyEvent) {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    //encode the string
    var encoded = btoa(tempvar); 
    container.innerHTML = encoded;

    var container2 = document.getElementById("container2"); 
    //decode the encoded string
    container2.innerHTML = atob(encoded);  
    
    var container3 = document.getElementById("container3");
    //decode the first 4 characters of the string
    container3.innerHTML = atob(tempvar.substring(0, 4));
});
```

```html
<div> btoa(tempvar): <span id="container"></span></div> 
<div> atob(decoded): <span id="container2"></span></div>
<div> atob(tempvar.substring(0, 4)): <span id="container3"></span></div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob</sub>

Comment: Okay, my bad. My example was not the literal problem that I am facing, it was just an example that a variable will not work as it should. My real variable is "totalprice" and when you click for example a button that has totalprice set to 10, the URL will be something like: "transaction.html?totalprice=10" and this is not working. It doesn't know what is "totalprice=10" but in https://www.base64encode.org/ it works without any problems. Sorry for the very late response, I have had some problems and could've not been here to develop my script. Thanks thought, and ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to *encode* using atob()? That function is used for *decoding*... instead use btoa() to encode...

Comment: Yes, I use this to make the url encoded:<script>
   var a = document.getElementById('50m');
   a.href = "transaction.html?" + btoa("totalprice=50");
  </script> but it doesn't work when trying to decode. EDIT: Idk but btoa() works but not atob() in that script.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it can't decode the string `"hello"`, try an actual string that can be decoded from base64, here is an example;

```
var tempvar = "aHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL3F1ZXN0aW9ucy80MzEyOTEzNi9kZWNvZGluZy1ub3Qtd29ya2luZy13aXRoLWJhc2U2NA==";
document.write(atob(tempvar));
```

If you want to encode, use the `btoa` function instead,

```
var tempvar = "hello";
document.write(btoa(tempvar));
```

You can use this website to test decoding and encoding base64, https://www.base64encode.org/

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are trying to decode a not base64 encoded string
that it works on hi is just a coincidence it seems.

atob = decode

btoa = encode

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong function. You should use `btoa()` to encode.

When you do `atob('hi')`, you're actually decoding 'hi', which happens to be valid base-64.